# ER-Diagram: Entity with unique attribute relative to another entity

Tags: entity-relationship

In an E-R diagram:
Let's say we have an entity owner and an entity pet.
A owner is related to a pet through the relationship adopts.
This relationship is one to many, i.e an owner can adopt many pets, but a pet can only be adopted by one owner.

Now each pet has a name that is unique among the pets owned by an owner, i.e an owner cannot have two pets named "Squiggles".
However, different owners can utilize the same pet names, i.e. Jack can have a pet named "Squiggles", and so can Jill.

How do I represent the pet's name in an E-R diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you want:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_entity

A pet would be unique identified by the owner id and its name.

The example in wikipedia sounds analogous to what you are looking for.

While this might not be exactly how you implement it in a DB this is how you would diagram it.

Comment: Thanks! Using the same scenario as above, I have a followup question, if you don't mind.
Now there is another entity Food, and the relationship Feed. An Owner can Feed his Pet with Food (hence an n-ary relationship) subject to the following conditions:
1) An Owner can only feed his own Pet
2) A Food (by id) can only be fed to at most one pet

I'm not sure how to draw out the two conditions in an ER diagram.